# The usage of "If", "else", "is.na()" in one function of R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have `Length` and `Weight` values in a data frame. However some of them are missing. The data frame is like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  L = c(13,15,19,NA,NA,32,35,NA,NA,18,15),
  W = c(NA,NA,50, NA,NA,NA,80,NA,NA,30,NA)
)
```

I need a function which will work when length is not `NA` and weight is `NA`. it will calculate the weight for length, and else it will do nothing.

```
lwr <- function(data, length, weight, a, b) {
  if(!is.na(data$length) && is.na(data$weight)) { 
    data$weight = 10^(log(a) + b*log(data$length))
  } else {
    data$weight
  }
}
```

Here we go

```
lwr(data=df, length = L, weight = W, a=0.003, b=3.2)
```

but it does not work.

If you help me, I would be appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the vectorized `ifelse()`, instead of `if()...else...`.

```r
lwr <- function(length, weight, a, b) {
  ifelse(is.na(weight), 10^(log(a) + b*log(length)), weight)
}

df |>
  transform(W2 = lwr(L, W, a=0.003, b=3.2))

# equivalent:
# df$W2 <- lwr(df$L, df$W, a=0.003, b=3.2)
```

```
#     L  W          W2
# 1  13 NA    250.4350
# 2  15 NA    718.8159
# 3  19 50     50.0000
# 4  NA NA          NA
# 5  NA NA          NA
# 6  32 NA 191078.5331
# 7  35 80     80.0000
# 8  NA NA          NA
# 9  NA NA          NA
# 10 18 30     30.0000
# 11 15 NA    718.8159
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably could do that easier.

```
f <- \(x, a, b) 10^(log(a) + b*log(x))

naw <- is.na(df$W)

df$W[naw] <- f(df$L[naw], .003, 3.2)
#     L           W
# 1  13    250.4350
# 2  15    718.8159
# 3  19     50.0000
# 4  NA          NA
# 5  NA          NA
# 6  32 191078.5331
# 7  35     80.0000
# 8  NA          NA
# 9  NA          NA
# 10 18     30.0000
# 11 15    718.8159
```